# Representing a number as the sum of two prime numbers

Tags: c, primes

What's wrong with my code? Why am I not getting any output?
*I'm practicing for embedded system.*

[running code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95pBh.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int checkP (int n)
{
    for (int i=2; i<n; i++)
        if(n%i==0)
            return (0);
    return (1);
}

int nextP (int n)
{
    do
     n++;
    while (!checkP(n));
    return n;
}

int main (void)
{
    int x = 34;  //user input
    for (int i = 2; i < x - 1; i = nextP(i))
    {
        if (checkP(x - 1)) {
            printf ("\n %d + %d", i, x-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Going till `n/2` in `checkP` function's loop condition is sufficient, instead of covering up till `n`.

Comment: `checkP(x - 1)` is `checkP(33)`, which is `0`, did you mean `checkP(x - i)`?

Comment: no! check (x-1) means, it is checking which is nearest  prime num from "x"

Comment: no, `checkP(x - 1)` will check if `33` (x-1) is a prime number, which is false, so it never executes the `printf`.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text, post text as text. Anyway it's pretty useless to show a screen shot that shows no output.

Comment: `for (int i=2; i <= n/i; i++)` is _much_ faster than `for (int i=2; i<n; i++)` for large `n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x-1` is always `33`, you want to use `x-i`, so that the sum of `i` and `x-i` is `x`.

The `if` should look like that:

```
if (checkP(x - i)) {
     printf ("\n %d + %d", i, x-i);
}
```

https://ideone.com/jAIfa2

Output:

```
 3 + 31
 5 + 29
 11 + 23
 17 + 17
 23 + 11
 29 + 5
 31 + 3
```